# Python plot with interactive dropdown menu

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, widget, ipython

I want to create a python plot of stock values where the ticker is based on a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is based on the columns headers of my pandas dataframe that contain the adjusted close prices of each company. The dataframe `data_df` contains my data along with the column headers that I want in the dropdown menu. If I run my `plot_w` without defining it as needing two arguments it can run. It cannot run when I pass `dataframe, ticker` into the definition. My goal is it should change the plot when I change the ticker in the dropdown.
My current code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd


def plot_w(dataframe,ticker):

    I = data_df.columns == ticker

    print(data_df.loc[:, I].head(10))
    #Code fails in the line below. 
    df = dataframe.loc[:, I].plot(x=dataframe.index, y=dataframe[ticker], style=['-bo'], figsize=(8, 5), fontsize=11, legend='False')

    plt.plot(df[ticker], label = ticker)
    #plt.plot(df["AMZN"], label = "Amazon")

    plt.legend(loc = "upper center", shadow = True, fontsize = "small", facecolor = "black")

    plt.show()

widgets.interact(plot_w,
    dataframe = widgets.fixed(data_df),
    ticker = widgets.Dropdown(
            options=data_df.columns,
            value='ATVI',
            description='Company ticker:',
            disabled=False,
        )
)
```

The dataframe is defined previously in the code.
Snippet of the dataframe [image: data_df] .
And a snippet of my error [image: error]

Comment: I find it weird that your code even runs, you execute `plot_w()` without any parameters, while `plot_w` takes two... However, could you add an example for what `df_final` would look like, since it is not defined in the code you posted?

Comment: @funie200 My plot runs if I dont pass any arguments into the definition of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by resetting the index of my  data frame and changing the line the error occured in to

```
plt = dataframe.loc[:, ['Date',ticker]].plot(x='Date', y=ticker, style=['-bo'], figsize=(8, 5), fontsize=11, legend='False')
```